# Format an amount to a specific display

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

I have a measure in Tabular that calculates an amount I want the display to be like below :

```
1 990K
```

I tried to use FORMAT but in vain.

```
MyMeasure :=FORMAT ( SUM(MyTable[Salary]), "#, 0.,,.0#K" )& "€"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the Properties :

```
#,##0, K€
```

[image]